# Weblogic setEnv properties on Yosemite do not work

Tags: macos, java

I am trying to use the WLST script tool from weblogic i have the following output

```
cd /Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/bin
Last login: Fri Nov 14 12:53:42 on ttys002
Cristians-MacBook-Pro:~ cris$ cd /Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/bin
Cristians-MacBook-Pro:bin cris$ ./setWLSEnv.sh 
CLASSPATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar:

PATH=/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/bin:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.9.2/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/cris/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.0.5/bin
```

Your environment has been set.

BUT it looks like the PATH is not kept

```
Cristians-MacBook-Pro:bin cris$ echo $PATH
/Users/cris/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

so i got :

```
java weblogic.WLST
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.WLST
```

Any idea why PATH is not set after running the  ./setWLSEnv.sh ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `./setWLSEnv.sh` runs the setup script in a subprocess; it sets the environment variables *in that subprocess*, and then exits... and the variable settings vanish along with that subprocess. In order for it to do anything useful, you must run the script *in the current shell process* with the `source` command, or its synonym `.`:

```
. setWLSEnv.sh
```